# django receiver only works with superuser status

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

in my users/models.py I have user creation which works fine.
I added this.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_userprofile(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    up, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
    if created:
        logger.debug(f"Created UserProfile for {instance.username} using create_userprofile(*)")
        up.save()
```

the UserProfile instance it creates only creates with superuser.  It doesn't matter I add the user through the normal sign up process or the admin.  When I change the status of the user to superuser the receiver is kicked off.  I want the receiver code to kick off every time.

Comment: Is this an extention to the Django User model or are you using Abstract user?

Comment: a minimal abstract user

Comment: Can you show the model manager for this User model?

Comment: good question: it doesn't have one.

Comment: check [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) Option3, and Option4, whichever you are using. This should help you move forward.

Comment: I did read that.  I have a manager for the UserProfile and it's just the standard Manager from django.db.models.  But User doesn't have one.  (I did try the one the article had at the bottom) User's save just fine but non-superuser's don't trigger the receiver.  How does having a manager trigger the receiver?